# Format document" in Visual Studio to insert braces around single-statement blocks for C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a way to "Format document" in Visual Studio 2015 to insert braces around single-statement blocks for C++ code?

For example this:

```
if (x)
    y();
```

should become something like:

```
if (x)
{ 
    y();
}
```

The auto formatting seems to deal with indentation, but not this brace insertion. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clang-format` to style your code as you want.
To add curly brackets you can set `InsertBraces` property as `true`.
For brackets style you can set `BreakBeforeBraces` property as:

- `BS_Attach`
- `BS_Linux`
- `BS_Mozilla`
- `BS_Stroustrup`
- `BS_Allman`
- `BS_Whitesmiths`
- `BS_GNU`
- `BS_WebKit`
- `BS_Custom`

Source: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a while back, the only formatter I found that looked like it would perform anything like this is the "Artistic Style" formatter:
http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html

The `--add-braces` option looks as though it would perform what you need, coupled with the `--style=allman` option.